# Remove launch screen, Xcode 7

Tags: objective-c, xcode7, splash-screen, launch

I can find a bunch of answers from pre-2014 about removing the launch/splash screen by removing the line "Launch screen interface file base name", but in this project on Xcode 7, there is no such line in my info tab.

Is there any way to remove the launch/splash screen in another way in Xcode 7? 
This is in Objective-C by the way.

Comment: Why don't you want the splash screen?

Comment: xcode 7 has that option too! Maybe you were looking at wrong plist. Pleae look at the info.plist of your project.

Comment: The launch screen is not optional. It is there, not as a splash screen to show a logo etc, but as a way to give the illusion that your app is opening instantly. Check the apple HIG. So, you can't remove it. But you can change it. What is it exactly that you want to do?

Comment: So, I have made a loading screen as the main view controller, so what it does is go from a static launch screen to a loading screen, which is a bit tedious to me. Here is a link to my info.plist file not showing the line : http://imgur.com/mRXXBak

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Contrary to an answer I received, you CAN disable the splash/launch screen. To do so:

1. click on your project
2. go to General
3. scroll down to App Icons and Launch Images
4. Change "Launch Screen File" to whatever your first view controller is, i.e. MainViewController

Your first view controller will now display instead of the Launch Image.

Comment: but it displays a black screen for one sec and loads the main screen. Do you have any idea to remove the black screen in beginning of the app?

Comment: You can't, you have to give the system some time to load the app.
That is why we use a launch screen, to display something instead of a black/white screen during the loading

Comment: How can I remove the whilte color when load the Main.storyboard

Comment: is there any solution for the black screen?

Comment: Did anyone got the answer for Blak screen? i am also getting blak screen.

Answer (score 9):

You can open XCode and try this:

[image: Xcode]

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a storyboard (not a xib file) and then add it to **Launch Screen File**.
Then you can have your custom splash view controller inside it.

Remember to mark your splash view controller as **Is Initial View Control**.

Answer (score 0):

Simple way to remove lunch screen in IOS (react-native)

Goto project IOS directory

> IOS -> Project Folder -> Base.iproj -> Open LaunchScreen.xib file

then remove < View > .... < / View > tag from file and save file