# Launch Screen issues

Tags: ios, xcode, uikit, uistoryboard, launch-screen

When I first started to create my app, I thought that using launch screens would be a good idea, so I added the `LaunchScreen.storyboard` file and created a view controller meant to be the launch screen.

Now, however, I would like to remove this launch screen now. I have tried to delete the view controller and the file itself, which does not work, as the launch screen view controller still appears somehow. I have tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37975826/remove-launch-screen-xcode-7), but nothing changed. I tried another answer(can't remember the link) which told me to delete a key-value pair in the project info. After doing that, the launch screen is gone, but a black screen replaces it, and the app is not full screen anymore on iPhone 8. There are black bars on the top and bottom of the screen.

My question is: how can I remove the launch screen completely without any side effects?

Xcode 9, Swift 4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Using a Launch Screen

It’s best to use an Xcode storyboard for your launch screen, but you can provide a set of static images if necessary.

Including static images will increase the size of your binary because you must include **all** resolutions (see below) otherwise you will see "black screen & the app is not full screen".

> Starting April 2018, all new iOS apps submitted to the App Store must be built with the iOS 11 SDK. All new apps for iPhone, including universal apps, must support the Super Retina display of iPhone X.

https://developer.apple.com/ios/submit/

So, you would be best off replacing the launch screen with a really simple view of your application (with no data).

Take at the Human Interface Guidelines for more information: https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/icons-and-images/launch-screen/

To quote:

> - Design a launch screen that’s nearly identical to the first screen of your app.
> - Avoid including text on your launch screen.
> - Downplay launch
> - Don’t advertise.

You can do this by using the menu bar:

```
File >
  New >
    File
```

[image: New Launch Screen]

Once you have created your new LaunchScreen.storyboard you need to ensure it's the one assigned to the application. You can do this either through the project file explorer or through the application plist.

[image: Ensure the Launch Screen File is set]

### Using Static Images

If you are really committed to avoid using a storyboard then you can migrate to using launch images inside an asset catalog by pressing the button above the launch screen storyboard.

[image: Migrate to catalog]

By migrating to launch screen images you will be required to provide **all** variants of screen sizes otherwise you will not support devices such as the iPhone X.

[image: Provide all the different static images]

[image: resolutions]

You might be required to delete the LaunchScreen.storyboard and delete the references in the project explorer / plist.

#### Final notes

- You may be required to delete **Derived Data** to remove any cached version of the launch screen storyboard.