# Disable splash screen on ios devices cordova

Tags: jquery, cordova, cordova-plugins, cordova-3

I just wanted to remove splash screen from android and ios devices permanently tried following tricks..and that only works for android.
any solution for **ios** ?

I've installed latest plugin for splashscreen.

**Config.xml preferences:**

```
<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="true" />
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="0"/>
<preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="0"/>
```

anyone know how can I do that ?

Comment: Why not just remove the splash screen?

Comment: To me more specific, simply remove the whole plugin from your project in command line

Comment: After removing splash plugin it shows me default cordova splashscreen, I don't need that too..

Comment: Since you accepted the answer that was mostly plagiarized from [Remove launch screen, Xcode 7](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37975826/4642212), surely this is a duplicate of that question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In iOS there is Launch images,

1. Click on your project from xcode.
2. go to General
3. scroll down to App Icons and Launch Images
4. Change "Launch Screen File" to whatever your first view controller is, i.e. MainViewController

Your MainViewController will now display instead of the Launch Image.

Try Like this :-

[image]

Even if you delete it from there.your will experience **black or white screen at launch.**

so for better user experience i'll suggest not to delete the splashscreen.

As it is shown in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46711606/3410174) by [Diogo Machado](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2425986/diogo-machado)

Comment: thanks for your answer..but I just wanted to disable splash screen any trick or patch ?

Comment: updated my answer.. you can do that..but you might experience black or white screen at launch for some millisecond.

Comment: I just tried to remove app launch images from ios platform folder but it still loads default cordova screen, can't determine issue :(

Comment: Can you elaborate exact steps, what should I do ?

Comment: added the image so u will get the better idea.

Comment: after delete don't run "cordova run ios" just run the app through xcode. otherwise it will override the cordova's default splash screen.

Comment: thanks for your answer..but I don't have MAC how could I do it from my windows machine ?

Comment: then you can't because even after removing the splash plugin..when you  run command cordova run ios default splash screen will be copied to the project, so you need xcode.