# launch screen should appear only for first time

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, launch

IF your launching ios application then launch screen should appear . And if your launching same app for second time launch screen should not appear. how to do this? Any suggestion?

Comment: Did you try to search SplashScreen (or so) on google or stackoverflow ? It looks to me like a question asked a 1000 times :)

Answer (score 2):

If you mean **Launch Screen Storyboard**, answer is, this isn't possible. This view appears every time that app's launching.

If you mean something like "home screen", you can achieve this by setting `rootViewController` of app's `UIWindow`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't prevent the App Launchscreen(.storyboard) from appearing when launching the app from scratch.

If you have your own "Launchscreen" that you show after opening the app, you could store a flag in the UserDefaults and check for it on launch whether or not to show it.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults

Potential duplicate of: [Remove launch screen, XCode 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37975826/remove-launch-screen-xcode-7)