# Animations on Splash-Screen

Tags: react-native, splash-screen

How to add the animations on the Splash-Screen in `react-native`. I have an `ImageView` on the Splash-Screen. I want to add the pulse effect on the `ImageView` or any other animations. I don't find any solution. please help me to do this. thanks in Advance.

code -

```
 <ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progress"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="10dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:indeterminate="true"
    android:theme="@style/progress"
    />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/splashlogo"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:src="@mipmap/myihalogo" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [react-native-lottie](https://github.com/react-native-community/lottie-react-native) for your animations in Splashscreen. Ive achieved that and it renders quite beautifully. Basically a JSON file which is the animations and that needs to be rendered.

Hope it helps. Feel free for doubts.

Comment: I can use this library in react-native components, not the android or .xml files. I want to the animation on the splash screen which is loaded before the app launch fully

Answer (score 0):

At first, I have searched many articles about changing ios's LaunchScreen.storyboard with lottie animation. However, Xcode enforces that LaunchScreen.storyboard should be static screen. So, I inserted animation code after static launch screen loading. Maybe, launch screen is essential, because it is loading screen for initial loading resource in ios. If you remove the launch screen, then ios app shows black or white screen at first loading.
[Remove launch screen, Xcode 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37975826/remove-launch-screen-xcode-7)

If you looking for animation launch screen in react native, i would suggest looking into this package.

> https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-lottie-splash-screen

It implements animation splash screen using airbnb lottie files. Also, I apply this for multiple react native projects and it worked well.
Have a nice day!